# cakephp form validation

Tags: cakephp, forms, save, validation

does anyone know if there is a VALIDATE function for a form in cakePHP and view the errors array? 
i.ve checked the documentation but the only thing i found is the SAVE function, i just need to know if the data i send is valid and review the errors manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->ModelName->set( $this->data );

if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
  // it validated logic
} else {
  // didn't validate logic
}
```

And read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/410/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller)