# cakePHP: how set error validation to input field manually in controller

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want  set error validation to input field manually in controller
example:

```
  if ($remainTime < 30) {
      ..... set error validation in here (error: limitTime ), ( error is not in model )
  }
```

**other question**: i want to ask :
bindModel ( in this case , I use bindModel in Behaviors ) 'll cause loss of relationship with other model 
but is bindModel cause loss of $var validate,too ?

Comment: For Cake 2.0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765236/applying-form-errors-manually did the trick for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if the $validate is defined in the model, bindModel wont cause closs of $var validate.

As for you primary question; you can set/unset/update $validationErrors of the models..eg

```
($remainTime < 30) {
   $this->Model->validationErrors['limitTime'] = "time is less than 30";
}
```

Answer (score 15):

This can be achieved using the invalidate method that will flag the field as having an error:-

```
$this->Model->invalidate('field_name', 'error message');
```

Comment: This is probably the more correct answer as this calls the Validator method that does _almost_ the same thing as the currently accepted answer. See the 2.6 API docs here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-ModelValidator.html#278-288

Comment: @neobie this is the correct way of invalidating a field in CakePHP 2.x. If this isn't working for you, you are probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: Please note that standard validators *reset* validation messages so `invalidate()` results are destroyed if you perform further validations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invalidate an associated model, you can use something like this:

```
$this->Model1->Model2->invalidate('Model2', __("Your validation message"));
```

In my case it invalidates **associated select multiple (HABTM)** field.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343472/cakephp-form-validation/3343830#3343830)

Comment: no, i want set error validation , in this case, $validate == null

Comment: Do you want to invalidate a field, or just to show that the form in general is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot has passed since this has been answered in order to pass correct message you need to put it like this:

```
$this->Model->validationErrors['limitTime'] = array("time is less than 30");
```

Form is expecting array of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

2019 update for CakePHP3
in `YourController.php`

```
// creane new
$entity = $this->YouTable->newEntity();

// or get existing from database
// $entity = $this->YouTable->get($id);

// invalidate fields
$entity->setErrors('your_field', 'error message');
$this->set('$entity', $entity);
```

and in `action.ctp`

```
// create form based on your entity
echo $this->Form->create($entity);
// and include your control
echo $this->Form->control('your_field');
```

if your form based on table, and for [modelless forms](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html) first you need to create `src/Form/YourForm.php` with schema definition and then call `setErrors()` on `YourForm` instance from controller.