# CakePHP Form validation using other models to validate and/or save?

Tags: cakephp

So my question is pretty much like the title. I have a form object called StudentApplicationForm. This uses some elements called grade_element_form.ctp, schools_element_form.ctp, student_element_form.ctp and guardian_element_form.ctp. All have their respective inputs built and sent to my StudentApplicationForm Model when the form is submitted. I want to use the Grade, School, Student and Guardian objects to validate the data before saving their respective information in their respective tables in the database.

I am able to build the appropriate  arrays to be sent to the models of each of the objects of the form and save them to the database. Now I want to make sure they are validated before saving though. Is the best way to approach this by using the:

```
$this->ModelName->set($the_data)

if($this-ModelName->validate()){
//true
}else{
//false
}
```

As shown here: [cakephp form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343472/cakephp-form-validation)

Comment: No, I'm asking should I validate like that. Not that I have an error. Because reading the Data validation (the validation() and set() functions) seems like what I want. Then after all parts of the form validated, save to the database, right? I'm just trying to make sure I'm going in the right direction for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the models are related, you can use $this->Model->saveAll() or $this->Model->saveAssociated() to save them all at once, by putting all the data in a single array, properly formatted, and saving that.

If they are not related, then you need to be using transactions, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html.  With transactions, there's no need to call $this->ModelName->validate() before saving.  Start the transaction, try to save each one, and if one of them fails, rollBack, and all the changes you attempted after you started the transaction will not be in the database.  If everything succeeds, commit it.

Example:

```
 $dataSource = $this->Model1->getDataSource(); 
 $dataSource->begin();

 if(!$this->Model1->save($array1))
 {
      $dataSource->rollback();
      $this->Session->setFlash('There was an error saving model 1');
      return;
 }

 //Continue the pattern for the other models...

 //If all the saves succeeded then...
 $dataSource->commit();
```

Comment: They are all related. A student may have many schools, a school may have many grades, and a student may have many guardians. Am I looking at associations? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html If not then the transactions may work.

Comment: In that case, yes, you should be able to use saveAssociated to save them all together.  You will have to use the setting 'deep' => true however.

Comment: The thing is before submitting the form, I need to create a code that is related to student, guardian, and school (and schools' grade table) and add that information into the form data to be saved. That code is a foreign key for all 4. So is there are way to insert that into the submitting form. I only want to create it if they are validated to save and then save the code along with all the associated models.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  You could try using hidden form fields, but passing around foreign keys through forms is often not recommended, so it may be better to determine which foreign keys to use by checking the database.

Comment: So I'm talking about creating the foreign key and saving it with the other data such as the student or guardian.

Comment: The foreign key is only created after validation of the data and saved with the data.

Comment: If you're creating all new data using saveAssociated or saveAll, CakePHP will automatically save the correct foreign keys, so you would not need to worry about that.  On editing, you will need to identify each model by its id, but if you do not have any field for the foreign key, the foreign keys will not change.

Comment: Okay. So how is the foreign key saved using the saveAssociated or saveAll?